# Event Log Security Exception After Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I just installed VS 2015 Community SxS with an existing VS 2013 Professional. Everything appeared to install correctly, however after the installation, when attempting to navigate to a locally hosted ASP.NET application on IIS, I get some sort of security exception related to the event logs:
[image]

I've found that if I manually remove the .NET Framework 4.6, the issue goes away (although then I can't use VS 2015.)

I guess I'm just looking for tips on how exactly to troubleshoot this further. I've scanned through the Event Log browser (ironically enough) looking for anything that might help pin the problem down, but can't find anything. I'm at a loss as to what else I can try.

Comment: Does your application run under the same application pool identity in 4.5/4.6? Does your application use partial trust? Just tried to see what other differences occurred on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that a particular HTTP module is somehow the culprit. It directly relates to another question I had posted (at the time I thought they were separate things):

[There is no EventLog source named 'ASP.NET 4.6.81.0'. This module requires .NET Framework 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659577/there-is-no-eventlog-source-named-asp-net-4-6-81-0-this-module-requires-net)

By commenting out the UnhandledExceptionModule through the web.config:

`<httpModules>`
<strike>`<add type="WebMonitor.UnhandledExceptionModule" name="UnhandledExceptionModule"/>`</strike>

`</httpModules>`

I've got things working. I'm still not satisfied however and will need to spend more time digging in and determining where the incompatibility lies.

Comment: It seems your module tried to find a source named 'ASP.NET 4.6.81.0' (probably according to webenbine's file version if you use the module from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/911816), but the actual source name in the registry is still 'ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0'. If that's the case, can you try hardcoding the source name to 'ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0'?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your application pool identity used by your application has read/write permission to the following registry Keys,

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security

You can see what's the difference (different identity or different permissions required by the keys) after you got 4.6 installed.

Besides, the first answer in this link might be helpful https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/00a043ae-9ea1-4a55-8b7c-d088a4b08f09/how-do-i-create-an-event-log-source-under-vista?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues.